# How to change path when application is running under load balance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, dns, routes, load-balancing

I am using asp.net MVC 4.0 application.

My application is currently on live server, also did load balacing for this. It is working fine.
My application is running on \ckfilexx\WebAPP\Webapp1 like https://www.xyz.xoz  and working fine.

Now I made a new webapi and deplyoed on \ckfilexx\WebAPP\Webapp1\webapi folder, and also this is working fine from every location of the world.
after 2 days I changed only the path of webapi to \ckfilexx\WebAPP\webapi and changed pointer from one server IIS to this folder also.

Now my problem is when I browse webapi like https://www.xyz.xoz/webapi from my computer it is in some xxx country.it is working fine. 
but when someone access this from another country yyyy it showing below error.

```
"HTTP ERROR 404.0 - Not found 
ther resource you are looking for has been removed,had its name changed, or  is temporarily unavailable.

Requested URL: https://www.xyz.xoz/webapi
Physical path \\ckfilexx\WebAPP\Webapp1\webapi"
```

Comment: it looks like a cache issue or DNS issue.

Comment: @Prashant, how to reset that DNS cache?

Comment: ipconfig /flushdns try this.

Comment: @Prashant - I did that,but still no luck. I think that is shared path and load balancer is running.so what to do? I have no idea about load balancer.